# Let's not have [legacy-code] be our legacy

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[legacy-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legacy-code) has 427 questions, 53 watchers, and the following tag wiki:

> Originally legacy code meant code 'inherited' from authors or from a previous program/system version. Since Michael Feathers published his "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" book, new definition came to be, where code without tests is legacy code.

### Burnination criteria:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?

No.  It just means (usually) that the question relates to old code, or code without tests, or maybe an old version of the language/libraries...

> and is it unambiguous?

No.  The tag wiki even states this: it could be either "inherited" code, or code without tests.  In practice, it also often just means "old code."

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Not really.  Questions about code that *is* legacy code are on-topic, but questions about how to handle legacy code in general are (when sufficiently specific) more suited to Software Engineering.SE, as they're usually architecture-type questions.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.  The fact that code is legacy code is not meaningful.  If there are relevant constraints (e.g., this piece of code cannot have major refactors for legacy reasons) those should be stated in the question, not implied by tags.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.  Looking through the questions tagged with it, it's hard to identify any strong theme.  It could mean anything from [the old version of the Android Support Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325092/use-legacy-support-library-option-in-android/208273) to [an old version of PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458975/how-to-find-function-calls-using-exact-number-of-parameter/208273) to a *wide* variety of questions about working with legacy codebases.

Comment: I have mixed feelings about it. On one hand it is kind of a meta-tag but on the other I think it can be useful in certain situations. If someone is trying to patch a legacy code without upgrading then letting people know is useful, because otherwise, we will suggest more up-to-date solutions. Letting people know that we are dealing with legacy-code could be useful, but the same can be achieved by putting a note at the start of the question too.

Answer (score 3):

I have somewhat mixed feelings on this too.

On the one hand, this is arguably a programming topic that someone could have "special" expertise in, and there are actually several books on Amazon.com about the topic (including one by no less than Martin Fowler, who wrote about refactoring existing - read, legacy - code).

On the other hand, the *way* that this is used does appear to be largely Meta. The mere fact that a programming problem occurred while working on code does not necessarily imply that solving it will require special knowledge of legacy code.

That being said, it's safe to assume that most people will not make that distinction. Few people actually read tag usage guidance, so these do little good.

On the balance, I say we burninate this.